# How to make only the UIImageViews in UICollectionViewCell overlap other cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, overlap

I've started working with UICollectionView few days ago, because I needed horizontal scrolling table. I'm creating a small application in which I am using UICollectionViewCells with negative minimumLineSpacing (cells are overlaping). Each of these cells have an UIImageView whose width is same as the width of the cell so part of the imageView is overlaped by adjoining cell. Is there any way I can make the imageView overlap the adjoining cell? I've tried to adjust the zPosition of imageView layer, but it doesn't seem to work.

I would like my collection view to look something like this: http://postimg.org/image/u24f6om9j/

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass's `contentView` and your `UIImageView`s, set `clipsToBounds` to `NO` and position / constrain your image view's frame to extend outside the cell.